# how to use rubyxl to access the first row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubyxl

```
workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse(params[:file].path)  
worksheet = workbook[0]
puts worksheet.sheet_data[0][0]
```

But I am getting this as output

```
<RubyXL::Cell(0,0): "0", datatype="s", style_index=1>
```

My excel sheet is of this form

```
    name    coupon
    gates   gates1234
    jobs    jobs1234
```

I want to access rows one by one .. any help will be appreciated.

I also made a sample app for this post, if you want to run it ..

`https://github.com/vamsipavanmahesh/example-excel-reader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
worksheet.sheet_data[0]
```

gives you a Ruby object representing the first row.

```
worksheet.sheet_data[0][0]
```

gives you a Ruby object representing the first cell on the first row.  But to get the actual contents of that cell, you need

```
worksheet.sheet_data[0][0].value
```

The worksheet is organised as an array of cells.  You have to deal with the cells one by one in each row, if you are processing the rows sequentially.

Comment: In sheet_data[0][0] first [0] represents row or column?

Comment: The first [0] is for the row.

Answer (score 1):

`worksheet[0].cells.map(&:value)` work for me

I was trying `worksheet.extract_data[0]` but **extract_data** is no longer available in RubyXL (I use v.3.3.3)!

Comment: NOTE, you'll want to use `.map{ |cell| cell&.value }` in case the `cell` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

```
worksheet.extract_data
```

give you entire sheet rows

```
worksheet.extract_data[0]
```

give you the first row